# How do I write a bash script to modify all file names in a directory after a given pattern?

Tags: bash

I am ripping some CDs and want to rename them all in a matching way.  The file names are of the form

```
chapter_[number 1,2,3,...]_name.mp3 .
```

I want them to be of the form

```
chapter_[number 01,02,03,...,10,11,...]_name.mp3 .
```

A few files also have something like

```
Disk_10_-_[number 1,2,3,...]_-_...
```

before the "chapter..."-part.

How can I write a bash script to

1. change the 1,2,3,... to 01,02,03,...
2. remove everything before the "chapter..."-part of the name ?

So far I only tried my rudimentary bash knowledge with `mv`, `awk`, `rename` and `grep` commands but I couldn't get the regular expressions to work...

Comment: Nothing in your samples has the strings `"chapter..."-part`

Comment: Just to be clear, `chapter_` is literal text (the names actually contain the word "chapter", not something like a chapter title)? A collection of actual names (original and desired, chosen to include tricky ones reflecting the corner cases that need handling) would be a useful thing to include in the question as test cases, so answers can be validated against them.

Comment: Also *before the "chapter..."-part.* ?

Comment: Also, it helps to make the question more specific if you _show_ some of the things you tried that didn't work; that way we can calibrate answers to focus on where you're getting stuck and avoid spending time going over things you already know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**cut**" to strip the beginning part.

Then you can use the AWK "**split**" function to separate the parts of the filename, so that you can then massage selected parts (2nd part) for your new file names.

You can also specify the **field separator** for AWK's line parsing.

The below demonstrates all these.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat >input.txt <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
Disk_10_-_1_-_chapter_1_name.mp3
Disk_10_-_3_-_chapter_2_name.mp3
Disk_10_-_12_-_chapter_3_name.mp3
Disk_10_-_5_-_chapter_4_name.mp3
Disk_10_-_1_-_chapter_5_name.mp3
Disk_10_-_9_-_chapter_6_name.mp3
Disk_10_-_10_-_chapter_7_name.mp3
EnDoFiNpUt

### Approach #1 - Splitting into arrays, then manipulating
while read line
do
    new=$( echo "${line}" | cut -f6- -d\_ |
        awk '{
        split( $0, parts, "_" ) ;
        printf("%s_%02d_%s\n", parts[1], parts[2], parts[3] ) ;
    }' )
    echo "mv '${line}' '${new}'"
done <input.txt

echo ""
### Approach #1 - Designating Field Separator for AWK line operations.
while read line
do
    new=$( echo "${line}" | cut -f6- -d\_ |
        awk -F "_" '{
            printf("%s_%02d_%s\n", $1, $2, $3 ) ;
    }' )
    echo "mv '${line}' '${new}'"
done <input.txt
```